# JSF 1.1 and MyFaces Tomahawk 1.1.9

Tags: java, jsf, tomahawk

I am trying to use the calendar component from Myfaces Tomahawk. I am running JSF 1.1 with Tomahawk 1.1.9 and Websphere 6.1. 
Looks like JSF1.1 and Tomahawk 1.1.9 are not compatible as the following code does not work -

```
<t:inputCalendar id="secondOne" monthYearRowClass="yearMonthHeader"
    weekRowClass="weekHeader" popupButtonStyleClass="standard_bold"
    currentDayCellClass="currentDayCell" value="#{dobBean.dateOfBirth}"
    renderAsPopup="true" popupTodayString="Shamik"
    popupDateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" popupWeekString="Wk"
    helpText="MM/DD/YYYY" forceId="true" />
```

When access this jsp page thru IE 7, it throws some javascript problem like popupcalender not defined. I found that java scripts are added in the rendered HTML page, but no idea why this problem ?

Any idea which version of Tomahawk should I use with JSF 1.1 ?

EDIT:

I already have Extension Filter configured in the web.xml file. Something like this -

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <!-- servlet-name must match the name of your javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet entry -->
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem today. This is something to do with websphere 6.1. I found the following [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-users/200906.mbox/%3C23998716.post@talk.nabble.com%3E) where people faced similar problem like I am facting. 
As mentioned in the above link, I added a custom propery com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility=true in the websphere containter by following this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rss=180&uid=swg21284395).

Comment: +1: You're entirely right, it's a Websphere matter. I in fact already knew this particular issue, I've seen/read it before at other forums, but I unfortunately didn't realize/recall that immediately when I read your problem. By the way, you're free to post and **accept** your own answers.

Answer (score 1):

Tomahawk is compatible with both JSF 1.1 and 1.2 (not with JSF 2.0 yet). The problem you're describing is recognizeable as not having the [`ExtensionsFilter`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/webapp/filter/ExtensionsFilter.html) properly configured in `web.xml`. Although the javadocs states that this is not needed anymore since Tomahawk 1.1.7, I would give it a try. Just define the `ExtensionFilter` in `web.xml` as per [this document](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/extensionsFilter.html). It's namely responsible for injecting the necessary scripts/styles in the response.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <!-- servlet-name must match the name of your javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet entry -->
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I had the extension filter in web.xml file. I can see the generated html has javascript in it, but it still does not work.

Comment: Looks like something do with WebSphere.